# Error : Linked AMP version is invalid In Blogger

Tags: blogger, amp-html

I created a blogger template that supports accelerator pages (AMP) , but when Inspect the link on google search console I get an error:

> Error : Linked AMP version is invalid

[image]

In my template I created two models:
The first does not support accelerated pages:
The second appears when I add `?view=amp` at the end of the link exemple:

> https://www.example.com/2020/01/post.html?view=amp

Please note that I added the meta to the template 
`<link href="https://www.example.com/2020/01/post.html?view=amp" rel="amphtml">`